# Sandbox payment with PayPal SDK over credit card

Tags: android, paypal, payment, cardio

I'm developing application with possibility of payments over credit card using PayPal Android SDK. For now - in sandbox.
I succeed in making PayPal native payment, as long as payment confirm and refunding.
But i cannot make a sandbox payment using credit card. No errors, no logs - after payment confirm activity just closes with no any intent data or so, and returning me to payment method choosing screen.
I tried to use some dummy credit card data there, and a real credit card too.
Can you help me with that issue? Can a reason be that my account belongs to country with disabled direct card payment (according to documentation, it's enabled for sandbox)? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i was having same issue but it there was actually some issues in paypal sdk 2.9.10 Paypal sdk version 2.9.11 is working fine with credit card payments. You can download the Paypal sdk version 2.9.11 from the link below. https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

Comment: Yes, actually, i'm the one who reported that bug on github.

Answer (score 2):

Recommend you using below tool to generate your testing credit cards:
https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/750

Comment: I tried to create test card for sandbox user, but i'm receiving an error "Card Number: You have entered an invalid or partial credit or debit card number. Please check your entry and try again.". And there's no "Generate CC number" button, mentioned in tutorial. Moreover, PayPal direct credit card payments don't require paypal-assigned card, am i wrong?

Comment: UPDATE: I found correct CC generator, and added one more card to sandbox account. But it's the same situation during payment in application.